# Either google map marker OR map will display, but not both?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, geodjango

I can't figure out what is going on here. The waypoints are data from my database and when I view the page source the correct data seems to be populating the javascript variables. The map is centering in the correct area where I want it to center, but the marker won't show up. The part I don't understand is that if I put in the waypoint.x/waypoint.y variables as the MAP centering coordinates, it will display as just a marker but the map itself won't display.

What am I doing wrong? I'm not getting any console errors or anything to troubleshoot with. I have my initialize() function in .

Script:

```
<script>
var map, waypointByID = {};

function initialize() {
    var map = {};

    {% for waypoint in waypoints %}

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 11,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.7484, -73.9857),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

    waypointByID[{{waypoint.id}}] = {
        name: "{{waypoint.name}}",
        lat: {{waypoint.geometry.y}},
        lng: {{waypoint.geometry.x}}
    };

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map, 
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(
            {{waypoint.geometry.y}}, 
            {{waypoint.geometry.x}}
        ),
        title: '{{waypoint.name}}', 
        visible: true
    });

    {% endfor %}

}

</script>
```

Output from view -> page source:

```
var map, waypointByID = {};

function initialize() {
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.7484, -73.9857),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);



waypointByID[294] = {
    name: "Holy Apostles Soup Kitchen",
    lat: -73.998837,
    lng: 40.7493372
};

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map, 
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(
        -73.998837, 
        40.7493372
    ),
    title: 'Holy Apostles Soup Kitchen', 
    visible: true
});
```

}

Comment: can you share a link to your website?  or to a jsfiddle demonstrating the problem?

Comment: I'm on localhost right now...could that be the problem? I haven't deployed the project yet.

Comment: i don't think that's the problem.  see if my answer below helps.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, you are creating a new map for each waypoint.

Try moving the map declaration above the `waypoints` loop:

```
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 11,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.7484, -73.9857),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

    {% for waypoint in waypoints %}

    waypointByID[{{waypoint.id}}] = {
        name: "{{waypoint.name}}",
        lat: {{waypoint.geometry.y}},
        lng: {{waypoint.geometry.x}}
    };

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map, 
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(
            {{waypoint.geometry.y}}, 
            {{waypoint.geometry.x}}
        ),
        title: '{{waypoint.name}}', 
        visible: true
    });

    {% endfor %}
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: The waypoints are lat/longitude for each object...I'll edit my code above to show what the page source gives me.

Comment: could it be that you are missing the call to initialize?  (added this call to my answer above)

Comment: additionally, do you have an HTML element to house the map?  (e.g. like this: `<div id="map-canvas"></div>`)

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't add those, but I do have a <body onload='initialize()'> tag on the page where the map is displayed, as well as a <div id=map> - the map is displayed just fine, it's just that I can't get the markers to show up when the page loads. The data for the waypoints is being pulled from the database so the user doesn't have to do anything to get the marker to show up, so I just want the marker to appear when the page loads.